# Does nanomsg have the concept of 'frames' as zeromq?

Tags: c++, nanomsg

I have been using zeromq for some time and use multipart message extensively. In C++, I use zmq_sendiov/zmq_recviov to send/recv multipart message. The benefit is I can put each message 'frame' in one iovec, and use the call to send/recv in one go.

Recently I decide to give nanomsg a try, I realize nanomsg has nn_sendmsg/nn_sendmsg which also use iovec. The question is: does nanomsg make sure that the structure of the iovec that is received being the same as the one gets sent? e.g., suppose I put

```
msg[0].iov_base = "Hello";
msg[0].iov_len = 5;
msg[1].iov_base = "World";
msg[1].iov_len = 5;
```

and send, will the receiving end get the same iovec array, with "Hello" and "World" in each element, or nanomsg is free to reassemble the buffer?

Thanks
Ralph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nanomsg-1.0.0 already support iov
[nn_sendmsg](http://nanomsg.org/v1.0.0/nn_sendmsg.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Currently in the documentation about this says nothing, but I sure that nanomsg make sure that the structure of the `iovec` that is received being the same as the one gets sent, because exist one unit test (see https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg/blob/fb5670c952c53834c5c7c989eace7c6bd54bd4c5/tests/iovec.c), which confirms my assumptions.